# Why is df command showing incorrect size?

Tags: embedded, embedded-linux, busybox, linux-disk-free

I am using a 64 MB QSPI formatted in some UBI partitions.

df is an applet of busybox 1.27.2

Actually,

```
~ # df -h
Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/ubi0_0               3.1T      1.9T      1.2T  63% /
/dev/ubi1_0               1.6T     21.8G      1.5T   1% /conf
```

But, obviously, the size cannot be that! Anyway, the use % seems to be correct, for the files contained in the partitions weight few MB.

How do you explain that?

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to fix the issue.

Busybox 1.28.0 commit d1535216 substitutes use of statfs with statvfs (https://github.com/mirror/busybox/commit/d1535216ca27047e3962d61b975bd2a638aa45a2).

I applied the commit to my project using Busybox 1.27.2 and, now, sizes are correct!

Thanks anyway.